# shell backup script renaming

Tags: shell, backup

I was able to script the backup process, but I want to make an another script for my storage server for a basic file rotation.
What I want to make:
I want to store my files in my /home/user/backup folder. Only want to store the 10 most fresh backup files and name them like this:
site_foo_date_1.tar site_foo_date_2.tar ... site_foo_date_10.tar
site_foo_date_1.tar being the most recent backup file.
Past num10 the file will be deleted.
My incoming files from the other server are simply named like this: site_foo_date.tar

How can I do this?
I tried:

```
DATE=`date "+%Y%m%d"`


cd /home/user/backup/com
if [ -f site_com_*_10.tar ]
then
rm site_com_*_10.tar
fi

FILES=$(ls)

for file in $FILES
do
echo "$file"
if [ "$file" != "site_com_${DATE}.tar" ]
then
str_new=${file:18:1}
new_str=$((str_new + 1))
to_rename=${file::18} 
mv "${file}" "$to_rename$new_str.tar" 
fi
done

file=$(ls | grep site_com_${DATE}.tar)
filename=`echo "$file" | cut -d'.' -f1`
mv "${file}" "${filename}_1.tar"
```

Comment: What's the exact problem you're experiencing with this?

Comment: for some reason it renames files like this:
site_foo_date_2.tar site_foo_date_4.tar site_foo_date_6.tar ...
on the next cycle:
site_foo_date_3.tar site_foo_date_5.tar site_foo_date_7.tar
So every second number is missing and I don't know why.

Comment: Works fine for me - what I'll do is just make a more resilient version of your code with explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that looping through all files in the directory with `ls *` without some sort of filter is a dangerous thing to do.

Instead, I've used `for i in $(seq 9 -1 1)` to loop through files from *_9 to *_1 to move them. This ensures we only move backup files, and nothing else that may have accidentally got into the backup directory.

Additionally, relying on the sequence number to be the 18th character in the filename is also destined to break. What happens if you want more than 10 backups in the future? With this design, you can change `9` to be any number you like, even if it's more than 2 digits.

Finally, I added a check before moving `site_com_${DATE}.tar` in case it doesn't exist.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date "+%Y%m%d"`

cd "/home/user/backup/com"
if [ -f "site_com_*_10.tar" ]
then
rm "site_com_*_10.tar"
fi

# Instead of wildcarding all files in the directory
# this method picks out only the expected files so non-backup
# files are not changed. The renumbering is also made easier
# this way.
# Loop through from 9 to 1 in descending order otherwise
# the same file will be moved on each iteration
for i in $(seq 9 -1 1)
do
# Find and expand the requested file
file=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "site_com_*_${i}.tar")
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
echo "$file"
# Create new file name
new_str=$((i + 1))
to_rename=${file%_${i}.tar}
mv "${file}" "${to_rename}_${new_str}.tar" 
fi
done

# Check for latest backup file
# and only move it if it exists.
file=site_com_${DATE}.tar
if [ -f $file ]
then
filename=${file%.tar}
mv "${file}" "${filename}_1.tar"
fi
```